# Join tables with Implied / Inferred data

Tags: sql-server, oracle, join, inference

This would be an easy join except: Table A is explicit for all times and values, but Table B only records rows when the there is a change from the previous value. In looking at Table B one can easily infer the missing times and values, but how to put that into a query?

Data in A.time contains every minute and a corresponding A.Value.

> A.Time...........A.Value
>
> 9:00...............3.4
>
> 9:01...............5.0
>
> 9:02...............5.3
>
> 9:03...............5.3
>
> 9:04...............5.3
>
> and so on…..

Table B only contains rows where the B.value has changed from the previous value.

> B.Time..............B.Value
>
> 9:00...................4
>
> 9:01...................4.1
>
> This is blank, but I know it to be 9:02  / 4.1
>
> This is blank, but I know it to be 9:03  / 4.1
>
> 9:04....................4.7
>
> and so on…

I need to do a query that links A.Time and B.Value, but I need the query to understand that a missing time in Table B should be substituted by the B.value of the first B.Time preceeding it.

Final table should be

> A.Time...............B.Value
>
> 9:00...................4
>
> 9:01...................4.1
>
> 9:02...................4.1
>
> 9:03...................4.1
>
> 9:04...................4.7

I am currently writing this for SQL Server, but I need an Oracle solution too
Thanks in advance;

Comment: left outer join on time

Comment: SQL-Server or Oracle?

Comment: John -- A left outer join would result in all the times from table A but NULL values where there was not an explicit B value.

Comment: Namphilbian -- Ultimately I need to run this in Oracle and SQL Server.  More immediate is SQL SERVER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, you can `LEFT JOIN` to get all the times and then use `LAST_VALUE(b.value) IGNORE NULLS...` to fill in the blanks.  (NOTE: the `ROWS BETWEEN...` part is redundant with the `ORDER BY` in the `OVER()` clause, but I like it for extra clarity).

Like this:

```
SELECT a.time,
       LAST_VALUE (b.VALUE)
         IGNORE NULLS
         OVER (PARTITION BY NULL 
               ORDER BY a.time 
               ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM   table_a a 
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON b.time = a.time
ORDER BY a.time;
```

Here is a full example with test data:

```
with table_a ( time, value ) as
  ( SELECT '9:00', 3.4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '9:01', 5.0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '9:02', 5.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '9:03', 5.3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '9:04', 5.3 FROM DUAL ),
table_b ( time, value ) as 
  ( SELECT '9:00', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '9:01', 4.1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '9:04', 4.7 FROM DUAL )
SELECT a.time,
       LAST_VALUE (b.VALUE)
         IGNORE NULLS
         OVER (PARTITION BY NULL 
               ORDER BY a.time 
               ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM   table_a a 
LEFT JOIN table_b b ON b.time = a.time
ORDER BY a.time;
```

An alternative (which *might* work on SQL Server) is to use `OUTER APPLY`.  Like so:

```
SELECT a.time, b.value
FROM   table_a a 
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT * 
              FROM table_b b 
              WHERE b.time <= a.time 
              ORDER BY b.time desc 
              FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY ) b
ORDER BY a.time;
```

Basically, this finds the most recent non-null value from table B for each row in table A.

#### SQL*SERVER Solution

Here is the `OUTER APPLY` syntax translated to SQL*Server:

```
with table_a ( time, value ) as
  ( SELECT '9:00', 3.4 UNION ALL
    SELECT '9:01', 5.0 UNION ALL
    SELECT '9:02', 5.3 UNION ALL
    SELECT '9:03', 5.3 UNION ALL
    SELECT '9:04', 5.3 ),
table_b ( time, value ) as 
  ( SELECT '9:00', 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT '9:01', 4.1 UNION ALL
    SELECT '9:04', 4.7 )
SELECT a.time, b.value
FROM   table_a a OUTER APPLY ( 
        SELECT * FROM table_b b 
        WHERE b.time <= a.time 
        ORDER BY b.time desc 
        OFFSET 0 ROWS
        FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY ) b
ORDER BY a.time;
```

Comment: Great Oracle solution!  Too bad SQL-SERVER doesn't have "IGNORE NULLS".  This will help me when I have to do the same thing on the Oracle database.  Now I just need a SQL Server version

Comment: You can also `OUTER APPLY`, which I believe SQL Server supports.  I'll add that to my answer.  Hope it helps!

Comment: I got that to work, but I had to add "OFFSET 0 Rows" just above the fetch line.  Great help.  In one post you concisely answered a lot of the same question I saw all over the internet for SQL-SERVER and Oracle.